# Why does this simple algorthim return always same value?

Tags: c#, algorithm, xna

I've written a simple algrithm to do aiming in 3D space. It should return a X, Y and Z rotation that is needed to point from `Start` to `End`.
For some reason it always returns the same values, regardless how I manipulate the `End`.
Something's gone really wrong here, but I just can't figure it out. Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
public static void CalcAngle(Vector3 start, Vector3 end, out float xAngle,
 out float yAngle, out float zAngle, bool Radians)
    {
        Vector2 xzPlaneStart = new Vector2(start.X, start.Z);
        Vector2 xzPlaneEnd = new Vector2(end.X, end.Z);
        Vector2 xyPlaneStart = new Vector2(start.X, start.Y);
        Vector2 xyPlaneEnd = new Vector2(end.X, end.Y);
        Vector2 zyPlaneStart = new Vector2(start.Z, start.Y);
        Vector2 zyPlaneEnd = new Vector2(end.Z, end.Y);

        float xrot, yrot, zrot;
        xrot = yrot = zrot = float.NaN;
        xrot = CalcAngle2D(zyPlaneStart, zyPlaneEnd); //Always 0.78539
        yrot = CalcAngle2D(xzPlaneStart, xzPlaneEnd); //Always -2.3561945
        zrot = CalcAngle2D(xyPlaneStart, xyPlaneEnd); //Always 0.78539
        if (Radians)
        {
            xAngle = xrot;
            yAngle = yrot;
            zAngle = zrot;
        }
        else
        {
            xAngle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(xrot);
            yAngle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(yrot);
            zAngle = MathHelper.ToDegrees(zrot);
        }
    }
    public static float CalcAngle2D(Vector2 v, Vector2 end)
    {
        float xlen = end.X - v.X;
        float ylen = end.Y - v.Y;
        return (float)Math.Atan2((double)ylen, (double)ylen);
    }
```

The result should be in radians.
Thanks in advice.

Comment: Are you passing same parameters to CalcAngle() ?

Comment: Typo in your question, or in your code? `Math.Atan2((double)ylen, (double)ylen)` - i.e. you don't seem to use xlen at all there.

Comment: That was the mistake!
I'm an idiot. seriously :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you notice that you use `ylen` twice in `CalcAngle2D?`

```
return (float)Math.Atan2((double)ylen, (double)ylen);
```

Use `xlen` where appropriate in `Math.Atan2(double y, double x)` and evaluate the correctness of the program.

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't you be returning `xlen` in `CalcAngle2D`?

i.e.

```
return (float)Math.Atan2((double)**xlen**, (double)ylen);
```